# How to add helper to `select` components `options`

Tags: ember.js

In the ember applicaiton, i am trying to sort my `options` values using a helper. but I am getting build error.

here is my code : `selectedCreditCard.balances` - array i am passing

```
    {{#rdc-form-select  label="Select Balance" 
        labelPosition="top" tabindex="0"
        options=selectedCreditCard.balances sortBy-amout //sortBy-amout is helper
        selected=selectedBalance
        searchEnabled=false
        renderInPlace=true
        onchange=(action 'selectedBalaceType' ) as |data|
    }}
    {{data.balanceType}} : {{data.amount}}
    {{/rdc-form-select}}
```

How to use helper with `options` in htmlbars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to use `(` if we need to use `{{` inside `{{`.

```
options=(sortBy-amout options=selectedCreditCard.balances)
```

Acutally you are using this for action helper.

```
onchange=(action 'selectedBalaceType' )
```